# Searching for a way for users to upload video content that will automatically format it for HTML5

Tags: html5-video

I am very new to programming so please excuse me if there is an easy answer to this question that I wasn't able to find due to my ignorance.

I have been searching for a way for users to upload video content that will automatically format it for HTML5 but have not found anything. I have figured out how to add video myself converting the files for the various formats but would like to incorporate into my site the ability to upload video files that will be able to play in my HTML 5 page without using a separate player or requiring the user to format the file for HTML5.

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Transcoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcoding) video formats isn't something HTML5 is capable of, and HTML version 1000 will never be capable of.

Realize that HTML (HyperText Markup Language) is a [*markup language*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markup_language) that runs on the browser, and even though HTML5 has some great video *display* capabilities, it doesn't have the kind of power a [*programming language*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_language) does. Besides, even if you wanted to do it on the browser (say, in [Javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript), which would be torturous), you don't want to have users transcoding video in their browser, because that is a very CPU intensive process that could take a very long time if they are using a computer with limited power.

You'll need a back end-processing platform on your web server (common ones are [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP)/[Java](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_%28programming_language%29)/[ASP.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET)) with [video codec libraries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_codec) to do this kind of thing, and even then, doing it programmatically isn't straightforward as there are so many formats, options and variables involved, and new codecs are introduced all the time that come and go for which you'd need to support.

One option I see out there is that you could pay for a 3rd party service to do it for you via an [web service API call](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service), like [OpenCrypt](http://www.opencrypt.com/video-conversion.php) or [Encoding.com](http://www.encoding.com/), but even using one of these services still means you'll need some back-end code on your website to make calls to these services.